# Can't get data to load in neo4j -- "no records, no changes"

Tags: neo4j

The other day I started moving a project I was doing from MySQL to Neo4j. I'm still fairly new at Neo4J, but I got everything imported and working fine. I stopped the server, packed my stuff up, and went home.

When I got home I started trying to fiddle with some of the nodes and edges but everytime I call `MATCH (n) RETURN n` I get nothing back -- All the browser says is "no records, no changes."

I thought that was a little weird, so I ran `MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)` just on a whim. It returns "154"

I've searched for this same error but nothing relevant shows up when I do.

Just to make it clear: This is *not* happening when I am trying to load the data from the CSV. The data is already in the database, it just won't *show up* for some reason.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I read you get nothing in the graph view. Never seen that myself.
Do you have results showing in the table or the code tabs ?

Do you have set labels ? Try your query with labels. There is presets in the browser that make the name property displayed for Person nodes, for example.

Maybe, all nodes are white on white with no id displayed.

Comment: Nothing shown in the table views. I have tried. I have a few labels `:Students`, `:User`, `:Classes`, `:Teacher` -- none of them pull any information

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth running the [consistency checker](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/consistency-checker/) to see if it detects anything off with the db.

You can only run this on an offline db, and it's usually best to run this on a copy of the db rather than the original db itself.

Comment: my `bin` directory doesn't have that. weird.

Comment: You're checking for `neo4j-admin` right? Are you using the executable community edition, or the zip/tar download?